# Restkit: Mapping parent reference to child object

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

Is it possible to write something similar to this code so that in the child objects I get a reference to parent object during the mapping process? Let's assume I have a child object with a property of type ParentClass called ***parent***:

```
RKPropertyMapping* parentPropertyMapping =
[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"@parent."
                                            toKeyPath:@"parent"
                                          withMapping:[mapping copy]];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:parentPropertyMapping];
```

I can later traverse from within the child objects to their parents.

## UPDATE 1:

The code above is used by any entity in the hierarchy of JSON objects (except strings, numbers, etc).  That is, it tries to set the linkage between the nested json objects and their owners (parents).

JSON response body:

```
response.body={"returnCode":{"messages":[],"name":"OK","returnCode":1}}
```

There is a ReturnCodeClass and a MessageClass both with a *parent* property. I'd like to have a reference (*parent*) pointing back to the owning (parent) object from these nested objects. E.g. from every *message* to the *returnCode*. In case of NSManagedObjects it is done automatically by the inverse relationship. But in case of NSObjects I try to emulate this behavior with using the @parent accessor.

Comment: Show the JSON. Are these nested children, or this is a request for children of an existing parent (so show how you make the request).

Comment: I've updated the original post. UPDATE 1

Comment: @parent refers to the parent source data object, not the mapping result. So you're trying to create a relationship on a normal (non-managed) object to the parent of a different mapping? Use a custom accessor on the parent...